# bash sed -i замена 8 на +7 в номере телефона

Tags: bash, sed, замена

Есть входящий запрос *GET* и переменная `$_GET['NUMBER']`. В переменной номер в формате 89123457890 надо номер преобразовать в формат +79123457890

Делаю так:

```
$_GET['NUMBER'] > ./num
cat num | sed -i "s/8/+7/g" > numer
```

Пишет:

```
sed: -I or -i may not be used with stdin
```

Если:

```
cat num | sed -i "s/8*/+7*/g" > numer
```

Пишет тоже:

```
sed: -I or -i may not be used with stdin
```

Comment: "s/8/+7/g"  разве не все встречающиеся 8 заменит на +7 ?

Comment: вообще ничего не меняет )))

Comment: я вот так тестил echo 89123457890 | sed s/8/+7/

Comment: если **это** как-то запускается из php скрипта, то мои глаза плачут кровью...

Comment: Не стоит решать проблемы регулярными выражениями, которые гораздо проще решаются обычными функциями работы со строкой.

Answer (score 1):

echo 89123457890 | sed s/8*/+7/

Comment: только как через echo пропатчить переменную или файл

Comment: Для работы с файлами есть отличная команда `cat`. А echo может и переменные выводить. И в любом случае это к sed не имеет ни малейшего отношения, его задача взять входной поток изменить его и отдать выходной. (хотя конечно файлы по месту от то же умеет менять)

Comment: @Mike, Ага, после таких советов весь интернет кишит *useless use of cat* (а также *grep*, *wc*, и так далее по вкусу).

Answer (score -1):

опция `-i` служит для того, чтобы внести изменения непосредственно в файл(-ы), переданный(-ые) аргументом(-ами). программа *sed* тогда «под капотом» сохранит свой вывод во временный файл, а потом удалит «основной» файл и переименует временный.

---

для замены `8` на `+7` я бы предложил такой вариант программы для интерпретатора *sed*:

```
s/^+7/&/;to;s/^8\?/+7/;:o
```

алгоритм такой:

- если в начале строки уже есть `+7`, то ничего не меняем и переходим к следующей строке
- если в начале строки есть символ `8`, то убираем его
- добавляем в начало строки `+7`

Comment: А если в номере меньше цифр (забыли 8ку)? Мораль: не стоит решать проблемы регулярными выражениями, которые гораздо проще решаются обычными функциями работы со строкой.

Comment: @0andriy *А если в номере меньше цифр (забыли 8ку)?* — проверьте. и моралей не потребуется.

Comment: Проверил, код Санкт-Петербурга 812.

Comment: @0andriy, и? что не так?

Comment: `echo '8121234567' | sed -e 's/^+7/&/;to;s/^8\?/+7/;:o'`
*+7121234567*, ничего, всё так. Расслабьтесь и получайте удовольствие.

Comment: @0andriy, 1. на вопрос я дал исчерпывающий ответ (по поводу опции -i). 2. предложенная мною **факультативно** программа в рамках изложенного в вопросе абсолютно корректно обрабатывает предложенный вами вариант (действительно заменяет первую восьмёрку на +7). 3. всегда рад вашим конструктивным комментариям

Comment: с sed я разобрался но через shell_exec не работает делаю так
<?php
foreach ($extract as $key => $value) {
file_put_contents("num.txt",$_GET['NUMER']);
$str = file_get_contents ( 'num.txt' );
$str = str_replace ( '8', '7', $str );
$output = file_put_contents ( 'numer.txt', $str );

if($value['fields']['sms'] == $output) {
    echo $value['fields']['name'];
}
}

?> но меняет все восьмерки в номере а надо только первую как сделать

Comment: сделал так <?php
foreach ($extract as $key => $value) {
$s = '89278564234';

$new_s = preg_replace('/^8/', '7', $s);
echo $new_s;

if($value['fields']['sms'] == $new_s) {
    echo $value['fields']['name'];
}
}

?>
но номер повторяет несколько раз а надо один

Comment: вынес переменную из foreach и все работает))